# How to capture images at the background using Camera2API?

Tags: android, android-camera2

1. I am a beginner regarding andorid.
2. I am using android studio as IDE, with an base android 5.0.

I am trying to build a game which do the following:

1.show the user a gui [a simple circle]

2.while the user look on the display, I would like to capture images from the front camera

most of the example\code snippets I found online either use the old Camera API or do not work .

GameActivity

```
public class GameActivty extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new com.oculid.ballmoves.GameView(this));
    }
}
```

GameView class

```
public class GameView extends View implements OnTaskCompleted{

    Circle circle;
    Paint paint;
    String TAG = "GameView";
    private MainThread thread;
    Client task = new Client(this);

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        circle = new Circle(100, 100 ,100);


        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(circle.x, circle.y, circle.r, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        circle.x = event.getX();
        circle.y = event.getY();
        invalidate();
        sendDataToServer();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I would like to create another class (using a Thread i guess) which capture images from the front camera at the background ( without showing any preview to the user)

Comment: The Android camera API requires that live preview should be displayed before taking a picture or video is stored, mainly because of privacy concerns. Nevertheless, there is technically nothing that could prevent your app to hide the preview surface behind some other view or views.

Comment: Can you explain how to "hide the preview surface behind some other view"? maybe a code a example? thx

Comment: "hide behind" is very [easy](https://gist.github.com/alexcohn/e1ed78a734f5cfe01a2616060c26b5ce)